# How to return the receiver instance's self from should_receive block

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I'd like to have instance methods of a class return self, and be init with another class instance self.
However I'm struggling to see how to spec this succintly:

```
::Api.should_receive(:new).once do |arg|
  arg.should be_an_instance_of(::Cli)
end
```

When running this spec, this ensures that the next method is called on true instead of the Api instance, as expected, that is the return value of the block. Example:

```
class Cli
  def eg
    api = Api.new(self)
    api.blowup # undefined method for true
  end
end
```

I'd really like the block to return the Api instance self without invoking another call to `Api.new(...)` in the spec, the example below does this and to my mind a non-rspec reader would wonder why the spec passes when clearly `Api.new(...)` has been called more than once.

Can anyone suggest how best to do this?

**Current solution:**
This reads like `::Api.new(...)` is called thrice: once to create `api`, once to create `cli`, once to create `start`. Yet the spec of one call passes. I understand why and that this is correct, so not a bug. However I'd like a spec that a reader not familiar with rspec could scan and not have the impression that `Api.new` has been called more than once. Also note that `...once.and_return(api){...}` does not work, the block needs to return `api` in order to pass.

```
let(:cli){ ::Cli.start(['install']) }
let(:start){ ::Cli.start(['install']) }
it 'is the API' do
  api = ::Api.new(cli)
  ::Api.should_receive(:new).once do |arg|
    arg.should be_an_instance_of(::Cli)
    api
  end
  start
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the original method (`new`) in a local variable and then use it to return the new `api` from within the block:

```
original_method = ::Api.method(:new)
::Api.should_receive(:new).once do |arg|
  arg.should be_an_instance_of(::Cli)
  original_method.call(arg)
end
```

This will run the expectation, checking that the argument is an instance of `::Cli`, and then return the value from the original method (i.e. the api).

Comment: Thanks @shioyama, thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it didn't workout.  I've added what I currently have, but it feels very inelegant. Hopefully this clarifies the question and you see a better approach?

Comment: Worked with a slight tweak that I've made and vladr approved.

Comment: Ah sorry missed the `call`! That was the key element, sorry.